# C++ getting undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 when using a pointer

Tags: c++

I know that "oh no I got this error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" questions have already been asked numerous times here, but none of them were able to help in this specific situation. I have a static pointer variable called "pointer" in my class's header file, and in a "GetSingleton" method, it will allocate memory for the variable if it doesn't exist, then return the variable. Calling the GetSingleton method gives me a linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Counter::pointer", referenced from:
      Counter::GetSingleton() in counter-440121.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Here's my code:

`counter.hpp`:

```
#ifndef COUNTER_HPP
#define COUNTER_HPP

class Counter {
    public:
        static Counter* GetSingleton();
    private:
        static Counter* pointer;
        int number_of_times;
        Counter();
        ~Counter();

};

#endif
```

`counter.cpp`:

```
#include "counter.hpp"
#include <string>

Counter::Counter() {
    number_of_times = 0;
}

Counter::~Counter() {}

Counter* Counter::GetSingleton() {
    if (!pointer) {
        pointer = new Counter;
    }
    return pointer;
}
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "counter.hpp"

int main() {
    Counter::GetSingleton();
    return 0;
}
```

And just in case, here's the compiler command I used:
`g++ main.cpp counter.cpp`

Anyone know why this happens?

Comment: You've declared `pointer` but haven't defined it. In one `cpp` file, add `Counter* Counter::pointer;`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Huh, it was that easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `counter.hpp` header file:

```
static Counter* pointer;
```

is a *declaration* rather than a definition - it simply declares that `pointer` exists, without creating it.

To *create* it, you need:

```
Counter * Counter::pointer;
```

somewhere, probably in `counter.cpp`.